# Proving that $\bigg|\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz\bigg|\leq2 $

Tags: complex-analysis

> Proving that $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz\bigg|\leq2\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\Gamma:$ from $z_0=-1+i$ to the point $z_1=1+i$

My try:

Let $\mathscr{L}:=$length$(\Gamma)=2,\,\,\,\,\,$ let $\mathscr{M}:=\max\limits_{\mathscr{M}\in \Gamma}|f(z)|=1\Longrightarrow\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z^2}dz\bigg|\leq\mathscr{M}\mathscr{L}\quad\blacksquare$

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: Yes. This seems correct. I assume that $\Gamma$ is meant to be the straight line from $z_0$ to $z_1$? Otherwise you could make $\text{length}(\Gamma)$ arbitrarily big.

Comment: Yes, it is a straight line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter what $\Gamma$ is - the integrand is analytic and so the integral only depends on the endpoints $z_0$ and $z_1$.  Thus,

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{dz}{z^2} = \frac1{z_0}-\frac1{z_1} = \frac1{-1+i} - \frac1{1+i} = -\frac{2}{2} = -1$$

Comment: It seems worth emphasizing that the analyticity is useful even if one can't actually find an antiderivative as in this case, as it ensures that the OP's use of the straight contour gives an upper bound on all such contours.